# How to Remove Duplicate Record from XML file using XLST by Muenchian grouping algorithm while keeping nodes having child nodes?

Tags: xslt

Here is my xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="/ns0:students/ns0:assignment[ns0:assigmentId[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('assigmentId', @id)[1]))]]"/>

<xsl:key name="assigmentId" match="/ns0:students/ns0:assignment/ns0:assigmentId" use="@id"/>
```

Here is my input:

```
    <ns0:students>  <ns0:assignment >
    <ns0:assigmentId Id="5326" />
</ns0:assignment>
<ns0:assignment >
    <ns0:assigmentId id="5326" />
</ns0:assignment>
<ns0:assignment >
    <ns0:assigmentId id="5326">
        <ns0:assignmentDetails>
        </ns0:assignmentDetails>
    </ns0:assigmentId> 
</ns0:assignment></ns0:students>
```

So, what I want to archive is I want to remove those duplicates ID's but I want to keep the "assignmentId" with child nodes.

The actual implementation is working smoothly (Muenchian algorithm) but it's not keeping the one with the child's nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there only one duplicate with child nodes?

Comment: I did not seen that scenario before but  we thought it will be only one. with child nodes.

Comment: Will each assignmentId have at least that one item with child nodes?

Comment: Dear Martin. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have a list of assigmentsId's (duplicates on the list).  So my aiming is to extract one single assigmentId from the list but it have to be the one with child nodes on it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that each group of `ns0:assignment` elements having the same `ns0:assigmentId/@id` has exactly one `ns0:assignment` element where the `ns0:assigmentId` element has one or more child element, then you could do:

```
<xsl:key name="assigmentId" match="ns0:assignment" use="ns0:assigmentId/@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:students">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:assignment[generate-id() = generate-id(key('assigmentId', ns0:assigmentId/@id)[1])]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('assigmentId', ns0:assigmentId/@id)[ns0:assigmentId/*]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy only those  `ns0:assignment` elements.